# Spelling of Middle English "narrow"

Tags: middle-english, paleography

What is Middle English spelling of "narrow"?

Studylight says "narwy", but in my opinion the forth letter is "r".

[image]

[Wycliffe's Bible (page 19)](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/)

Mt.7:14

[Studylight:](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=Hou&search_form_type=general&q1=Matthew%207%3A14&s=2&t1=en_wyc&ns=0)

"...hou streit is the yate, and narwy the weye, that ledith to lijf, and ther ben fewe that..."

King James Bible:

"Because strait is the gate, and narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life, and few there be that..."

Comment: There is no single Middle English spelling of *narrow*. OED gives *narouȝ, narwe, narroy, narrowe,* and around 30 others. It looks to me like your manuscript spells it *narwy*, as Studylight says.

Answer (score 4):

The spelling in the manuscript is *narwʒ*. The shape of the [w] between *narwʒ* and *wei* is consistent, as is the [r] between it and *streit* and the [a] between it and *ʒat*. The yogh [ʒ] is consistent between it and *ʒat* as well; it appears Studylight represents the yogh as a [y].

Middle English has no single consistent spelling. Especially for this word, according to the Middle English Dictionary ("[narw and narwe](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED29091)") we have:

> narw(e adj. Also nareu(e, narewe, narow(e, nareuʒe, narouʒ(e, narouʒh, narough, nareuh, naru(e, narru, narʒ, nargh, **narwʒ**, narwh, nare & nerue & (early) nearw(e, near(u(we, nerw, nærewe, nærewne, (early SEM) nerewe, (early SWM) nearewe, nearow(e, neruwe, neruh.

While the absence of a vowel between [r], [w], and [ʒ] may send shivers down the spine of a first year Middle English student, we also see this in Middle English with words like *[borwʒ](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED6329/track?counter=1&search_id=1187236)* (modern *burrow*) and *[merwʒ](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED26987/track?counter=2&search_id=1187236)* (modern *marrow*).